# Get the parent object in Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I have classes with bidirectional connection to one another.
When Ninject create the class `Parent`, it also creates a `Child`. The problem is that the `Child` must know who its parent is. But I can not find any information in `IContext` about the parent object.

```
//The parent
class Parent:IParent
{
   public Parent(Child child) {...}
}

//The child needing to know who its parent is
class Child:IChild
{
   public Child(Parent parent) {...}
}

//The Ninject binding
Bind<IChild>().To<Child>.WithConstructorArgument("parent", x=>GetParent(x));
Bind<IParent>().To<Parent>;
Bind<IFactory>().ToFactory();

//Method to get the constructor parameter to Child containing the parent
private IParent GetParent(IContext context)
{
    // Should return the IParent that requested this IChild
}
```

When I call `IFactory.CreateParent()` I want to get a Parent that have a bidirectional connection to a Child.

Comment: Can you, please, explain in detail what you want to accomplish? When you call `Resolve<T>` you don't pass any information about the  caller into kernel.

Comment: I saw that I wrote a bit wrong for Bind. It is corrected now

Comment: When I call IFactory.CreateParent() I want to get a Parent that have a bidirectional connection to a Child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't.

What you have here is a `circular reference`, which is a bad thing.
What you're saying in the ctors is: I need a parent to be able to create a child and to be able to create that parent I need the child. One of them needs to be created first, and none of them can because they need the other in the ctor.

You need to use the `Mediator` pattern to get rid of it, or as a last resort use `Property Injection` to get it working.